# Print all frames in between set key frames?

Tags: python, objects

How could i have blender print all frames in between a set of key frames? For example, one is at 0, then another at 10. So it would print all 10 frames.

Code:

```
import bpy
import math

selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

def get_keyframes(obj_list):
    keyframes = []
    for obj in obj_list:
        anim = obj.animation_data
        if anim is not None and anim.action is not None:
            for fcu in anim.action.fcurves:
                for keyframe in fcu.keyframe_points:
                    x, y = keyframe.co
                    if x not in keyframes:
                        keyframes.append(math.ceil(x)) #(math.ceil(x)))
    return keyframes

def print_details(obj_list):
    XRot = round(obj_list.rotation_euler.x, 2)
    ZRot = round(obj_list.rotation_euler.z, 2)
    YRot = round(obj_list.rotation_euler.y, 2)
    xloc = round(obj_list.location.x, 2)
    yloc = round(obj_list.location.y, 2)
    zloc = round(obj_list.location.z, 2)
    print(obj_list.name)
    print("X Rot : ", XRot, '\t'*2, "Y Rot : ", YRot, '\t'*2, "Z Rot : ", ZRot)
    print("X Loc : ", xloc, '\t'*2, "Y Loc : ", yloc, '\t'*2, "Z Loc : ", zloc)




print("-"*25, "starting","-"*25)
for keys in range of (get_keyframes(selection)): #This part needs to be in range of keyframes. Gives list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer error
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(key)
    print("key : ", key)
    for obj in selection:
        print_details(obj)
print("-"*25, "ending","-"*25)
```

The issue with this, the way keyframes are defined i cannot do a range of them.

Comment: try this 
'my_frames = get_keyframes(selection)
for key in range(my_frames[0], my_frames[len(my_frames)-1]+1):'

Comment: Thanks it works great! Out of curiosity what does that +1 do at the end?

Comment: If you iterate through the range of a list my_frames[0] being the 1st item in the list my_frames[-1] being the last item in the list the loop will stop when it finds the last item instead of performing the actions on the last item. Since you wanted the details of the last item as well (my_frames[-1])+1

Comment: Instead of rounding and then using multiple parameters to `print()`, use string formatting, like `print("X Rot : %.2f\t\tY Rot : %.2f\t\tZ Rot : %.2f" % (XRot, YRot, ZRot)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the script you're looking for. For each selected object it finds the frame range over which it is animated, and then prints its rotation and location for each frame in that range.

Note that I've also added some important bits, like documenting what a function does, and declaring its return type. Furthermore, I simplified the `print_details()` function, and I'm using the Blender naming convention `ob` to indicate the object.

```
import math
import typing

import bpy


def find_animated_range(ob) -> typing.Tuple[int, int]:
    """Returns the frame range containing animation of the object.

    :returns: a tuple (min frame, max frame) of the animated range.
        If there is no animation, returns values such that
        min > max
    """

    fmin = bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1
    fmax = bpy.context.scene.frame_start - 1

    anim = ob.animation_data
    if not anim or not anim.action:
        return fmin, fmax

    for fcu in anim.action.fcurves:
        fmin = min(fmin, fcu.keyframe_points[0].co.x)
        fmax = max(fmax, fcu.keyframe_points[-1].co.x)

    return fmin, fmax


def print_details(ob):
    rot = ob.rotation_euler
    loc = ob.location
    print("X Rot : %.2f\t\tY Rot : %.2f\t\tZ Rot : %.2f" % (rot.x, rot.y, rot.z))
    print("X Loc : %.2f\t\tY Loc : %.2f\t\tZ Loc : %.2f" % (loc.x, loc.y, loc.z))


print("-"*25, "starting","-"*25)

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    fmin, fmax = find_animated_range(ob)
    if fmin > fmax:
        # Not animated
        continue

    print(ob.name)
    for frame in range(fmin, fmax+1):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
        print("key : ", frame)
        print_details(ob)

print("-"*25, "ending","-"*25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but just some general cleanup of your code:

- Using generators instead of single-use lists.
- Using string formatting.
- Adhering to PEP-8 when it comes to naming things.
- Using `continue` to reduce indentation level.
- Using a `set` to do lookups, rather than a list.
- Renamed `obj_list` to `obj`, because it holds an object and not a list.

---

```
import bpy

import bpy
import math

selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

def get_keyframes(obj_list):
    keyframes = set()
    for obj in obj_list:
        anim = obj.animation_data
        if not anim or not anim.action:
            continue

        for fcu in anim.action.fcurves:
            for keyframe in fcu.keyframe_points:
                x, y = keyframe.co
                ceil = math.ceil(x)
                if ceil not in keyframes:
                    keyframes.add(ceil)
                    yield ceil

def print_details(obj):
    xrot = obj.rotation_euler.x
    yrot = obj.rotation_euler.y
    zrot = obj.rotation_euler.z
    xloc = obj.location.x
    yloc = obj.location.y
    zloc = obj.location.z
    print(obj.name)
    print("X Rot : %.2f\t\tY Rot : %.2f\t\tZ Rot : %.2f" % (xrot, yrot, zrot))
    print("X Loc : %.2f\t\tY Loc : %.2f\t\tZ Loc : %.2f" % (xloc, yloc, zloc))


print("-"*25, "starting","-"*25)
for keys in range of (get_keyframes(selection)): #This part needs to be in range of keyframes. Gives list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer error
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(key)
    print("key : ", key)
    for obj in selection:
        print_details(obj)
print("-"*25, "ending","-"*25)
```